# where does this $post_id come from?

Tags: save-post, quick-edit

I was trying to figure out why `save_post` wasn't being fired upon 'Quick edit', and found the solution [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/action-hooks-not-working-in-quick-edit) - apparently global `$post` is not available when updating a post in Quick edit mode.

So - I got it working now - see working example below, but I don't understand *why* it's working.

```
function mytestfunc($post_id) 
{
    $key = 'test';
    $data = 'this is a test';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'mytestfunc' );
```

Can someone explain to me where this `$post_id` is coming from? I'm not passing the value in `add_action` - so I don't understand why `mytestfunc` knows which post I'm targeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from `wp_insert_post()`, where `do_action()` is called with two additional parameters:

```
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

So it is not *you* who adds the parameters, it is WordPress.

If you register your callback with the fourth parameter set to `2` …

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'mytestfunc', 10, 2 );
```

… you will even get the complete `$post` object:

```
function mytestfunc( $post_id, $post )
```